# How do I reach the mediaFile on my viewmodel and use it on my contentpage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get the underlying image data from when you select a picture. The function itself with the cameraalbum and selecting a picture works perfectly and I am only missing one thing and that is to get the image data. The imagedata is inside the returned mediaFile i assume but I am not sure how I can reach it on my contentPage.

(I use this project: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera )

The idea is to send the imagedata to my database on the contentpage.

This is the viewmodel named "CameraViewModel":

```
public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;

        try
        {
            var mediaFile = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = mediaFile.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => mediaFile.Source);


        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;

        }
    }
```

On my contentpage right now I have this:

```
CameraViewModel cameraOps = null;

    public PhotoPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        cameraOps = new CameraViewModel ();
        cameraOps. //trying to reach the mediafile here 
    }
```

Updated code:

```
private MediaFile _file;
    public MediaFile File
    {
        get { return _file; }
        set
        {
            _file = value;
        }
    }

public async Task SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup ();

        ImageSource = null;

        try
        {
            File = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
                {
                    DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                    MaxPixelDimension = 400
                });

            VideoInfo = File.Path;
            ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => File.Source);


        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;

        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        File = value as MediaFile;
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => File.Source);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest disposing of the `mediaFile` in a `finally` once you are done with it: `finally { if(mediaFile != null) { mediaFile.Dispose(); } }`

Comment: Do i add it inside the SelectPictureFunction? And how would I be able to reach it afterwards on my ContentPage?

Comment: Yes it would go after the `catch()` in `SelectPicture()`. You would want to assign it to a ViewModel property within the `try`, like @EgorGromadskiy shows in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create property on view model:

```
    private MediaFile _file;
    public MediaFile File
    {
        get { return _file; }
        set
        {
            _file = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

And then bind it on `ContentPage`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding File}, Converter={StaticResource MediaFileToImageSourceConverter}">
```

Converter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         var file = value as MediaFile;
         return ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream()));
    }
```

**Updated code:** (not in best traditions of mvvm, but for your sample)

```
    public async Task<MediaFile> SelectPicture()
    {
        Setup();

        MediaFile file = null;

        try
        {
            file = await _Mediapicker.SelectPhotoAsync(new CameraMediaStorageOptions
            {
                DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Front,
                MaxPixelDimension = 400
            });

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Status = ex.Message;
        }

        return file;
    }
```

On code behind:

```
    public async void OnTakePhotoButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var file = await cameraOps.SelectPicture();
        someImage.ImageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.Source);
    }
```

Comment: So I add the converter on my contentpage as well then? I cannot find the command 'GetStream'.

Comment: Sorry, instead use your solution `ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.Source));`

Comment: OnPropertyChanged(); error: No overload for method onpropertychanged takes 0 arguments

Comment: From which class your view model is inherited?

Comment: @medvedo  Read up on Xamarin's [MVVM Binding](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/) guide, specifically the first part where it talks about inheriting from `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Do I add the Convert in the viewmodel or on my contentpage?

Comment: Create converter and implement `IValueConverter` interface. Here is related [topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18849/how-do-i-use-ivalueconverters)

Comment: It is inside File. But why do I need that snippet of code inside my XAML?

Comment: If you don't use XAML, so create a method on view model, that will return `MediaFile`. Than use this method from view. And do all converter's staff on view.

Comment: Check out my updated code on the post (in the end under "Updated code:"). Am I doing it right so far on the viewmodel?

Comment: I have not yet solved it but I will give you the answer because you stirred me into the right direction. I will make a new post within the hour with my new code.

Comment: @medvedo check out my updated code. It's not in best practice, but should work.

Comment: Okay, so the correct format is when the image is an "Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource" and not an "Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource" when I try to send it to a database?

Comment: [ImageSource.FromStream](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromStream/p/System.Func%7BSystem.IO.Stream%7D/) returns `ImageSource` and [Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/) has property `Source` that is `ImageSource`, too.

Comment: Okok! I have trouble now with sending the image to my db. That is another story though. I will make a post about that shortly. Thanks alot for the help here!!

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help!